# Need syntax help for python caeasar cipher one liner with input from bash echo command

Tags: python, bash, piping

I am attempting to write a python one liner for a caeasar cipher the takes input from echo and shifts it 3 characters. when I run it I get a syntax error message. I would appreciate it if someone could point out where I am getting the syntax wrong. I am using python 2.6 on cent os 6.

~ $ echo "HELLO" | python -c "import sys; print ' '.join(chr(ord(line)+3ys.stdin])"

File "", line 1

```
import sys; print ' '.join(chr(ord(line)+3)[for line in sys.stdin])
                                              ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Of course the out put should print: KHOOR.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate syntax error is because of the square brakets you're putting around `for line in sys.stdin`. Those are unnecessary and should simply be dropped.

However, you're still going to have an issue with your code, because you're calling `ord` on a full line, not just a single character. You probably need an additional loop to iterate over the characters of each line. In the following code, that's what I do, with the further addition of stripping the line so that we don't try to shift the newline character to something strange:

```
import sys; print "\n".join("".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in line.strip()) for line in sys.stdin)
```

Comment: ~ $ echo "HELLO" | python -c "import sys; print " ".join("".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in line.strip()) for line in sys.stdin)"                                                      Thanks for your help. When I do what you suggest it seems to print a blank line or line of blanks.

Comment: Be careful with quotation marks on the command line! I suspect things are getting garbled between your shell and Python. On windows I got it to work by using single quotes in the Python code and double quotes for the shell. On a Unix-like system I think either will work in either place, just don't use the same ones both places (unless you want to escape the inner ones).

Comment: Use for instance `echo "HELLO" | python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join("".join(chr(ord(char)+3) for char in line.strip()) for line in sys.stdin)'
`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it. I am new to python and I try to keep it simple put the task is awfully complicated for a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
import sys; print ' '.join([chr(ord(line)+3) for line in sys.stdin])
                           ^
```

[Doc for list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems ord only likes it when it gets a character not a string.                                                     bob@pbx:~ $ echo "HELLO" | python -c "import sys; print ' '.join([chr(ord(line)+3) for line in sys.stdin])"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found